# Can we get the formula for $\prod\limits_{k=0}^n{(1+2^k)^2}$ in terms of $n$?

Tags: asymptotics, intuition, products

Can we get the formula for $\prod\limits_{k=0}^n{(1+2^k)^2}$ in terms of $n$?

Comment: I'm interested in the asymptotic bounds of this formula, as well.

Comment: This is equivalent to finding an expression for $$\prod_{k=0}^n(1+2^k)$$ and then just squaring it. Perhaps that will help simplify the problem to some degree.

Comment: We have $\prod_x{f(x)} = e^{\sum_x{\log{f(x)}}}$ from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_product

Comment: @sos440:  If you write this up, detailing how you got the $2^{n(n+1)/2}$, I would accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Cameron Williams pointed out, it suffices to consider the non-squared version. But note that

$$ \prod_{k=0}^{n} (2^{k} + 1) = \prod_{k=0}^{n} 2^{k}(1 + 2^{-k}) = \left( \prod_{k=0}^{n} 2^{k} \right)\left( \prod_{k=0}^{n} (1 + 2^{-k}) \right). $$

Taking logarithm, we find that

$$ \log \prod_{k=0}^{n} 2^{k} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} k \log 2 = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\log 2
\quad \Longrightarrow \quad \prod_{k=0}^{n} 2^{k} = 2^{n(n+1)/2}. $$

On the other hand,

$$ \log \prod_{k=0}^{n} (1 + 2^{-k}) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \log(1 + 2^{-k}), $$

which converges as $n \to \infty$ by limit comparison test with $\sum_{k=0}^{n} 2^{-k}$. So if we denote

$$C = \prod_{k=}^{\infty} (1 + 2^{-k}),$$

then we get

$$ \prod_{k=0}^{n} (2^{k} + 1) \sim C 2^{n(n+1)/2}. $$

A relatively fast-converging series expansion for $\log C$ can be obtained by Fubini's Theorem:

$$ \log C = \log 2 + \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{j-1}}{j(2^{j} - 1)} \approx 4.7684620580627434483 \cdots. $$

Comment: A part of me believes someone should find a way to post this bounds to OEIS.  Another part isn't sure what to do...  You're brilliant!  Would you ever consider posting this to OEIS?

Comment: The series in the last display is an alternating series of decreasing terms, so it's bounded above by its first term, which is $1$. So, $C\le1+\log2<1.7$. The $4.76\dots$ evaluation must be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is all that is known about this sequence on OEIS.](https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C+6%2C+30%2C+270%2C+4590&language=english&go=Search) (Or rather, the sequence before squaring it.) I see no formulas that are not recursive or do not involve $\sum$ or $\prod$.